# Swiftmailer.Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()

Tags: php

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой, которую я получаю.
`Swiftmailer` выдает мне такую ошибку:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in sendmail.php on line 3

Вот сам код:

```
<?php
$autoload = require_once '/../../autoload.php';
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls');
->setUsername('test')
->setPassword('test')
->setAuthMode('login');

if(isset($_POST['form'])){
if($_POST['form']=='contact-us'){
    $name = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['name'])));
    $mail = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['mail'])));
    $phone = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])));
    $message = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['message'])));
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $message_text='<b>'.$subject.'</b><br>';
    $message_text.='Name: '.$name;
    $message_text.='<br>E-Mail: '.$mail;
    $message_text.='<br>Phone: '.$phone;
    $message_text.='<br>Message: '.$message;
}
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
$message = new Swift_Message();
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setFrom(array('test' => "trs"))
    ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
    ->setBody($message_text, 'text/html');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
echo json_encode($_POST); }
```

Comment: `Вызов неопределенного метода Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()` - нет его там.

Answer (score 1):

Пора использовать `new Swift_SmtpTransport`. Статический метод `newInstance` в Swiftmailer отовсюду убрали, смотрите [коммит](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/commit/5a0199b1ac8409791086098557da53b1cc92fc04), [патчноутс](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/CHANGES) к версии 6.0.0.

UPD

```
$message = new Swift_Message();
    ->setSubject($subject)
```

Явно ошибка. Должно быть, к примеру, так

```
$message = new Swift_Message();
    $message->setSubject($subject)
//остальные сеттеры и ;
```

Comment: окей, я заменил на new, но почему то получил 500 ошибку и мой файл лег. в чем может быть причина, синтаксическая ошибка ? дополнил свой код.

Comment: @Kek начните поиск конкретной ошибки отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5. Будет ошибка, сможем разобраться.